# Jlog Getinstance in Joomla 3.0?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I made a small extension for Joomla 2.5 and it worked.
But the issue is when i trying to make it compatible with Joomla 3, I get errors about JLog::getInstance method is not found.
I know that they removed it and it got replaced by JLogLogger but that is also not working.

Can someone please help me and make it work?
The code I am using in Joomla 2.5 is

```
$log = JLog::getInstance();
$log->addEntry(array('comment' => $server['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " is allowed"));
```

I made a variable called $log because I am using it more.
This is just a small code from the extension.

Comment: For future reference of people I have since started a docs page ont this here. http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog .

Answer (score 3):

This code is from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586142/logging-in-joomla-platform-11-jlog):

```
jimport('joomla.log.log');

JLog::addLogger(
    array(
            // Set the name of the log file
            'text_file' => 'test.log.php',
            // (optional) you can change the directory
            'text_file_path' => 'somewhere/logs'
     )
);

// start logging...
JLog::add('Starting to log');
```

If the code above doesn't work, try adding `jimport('joomla.log.log');` to the top of the file on it's own instead.

Hope this helps