# extension development - How to prevent unrelated log entries from showing up in custom log?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Part of this question was already asked here: [Joomla >1.7 hide log messages from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389103/joomla-1-7-hide-log-messages-from-browser)

The Problem:

In my extension, I want to create a custom logger. For that, I do the following:

```
JLog::addLogger(array(
    'text_file' => 'plg_system_myplg.log.php',
    JLog::ALL,
    array('myplg')
));
```

and subsequently, to log something:

```
$log->addEntry(array('comment' => $someMsg, 'level' => $someLogLevel));
```

My problem is, that in my log file (plg_system_myplg.log.php), some messages completely unrelated to my plugin show up; e.g.:

```
... NOTICE Can't identify browser version. Agent: ...
```

or

```
... INFO FinderIndexerAdapter::getTypeId
```

The common thing about them is that they get entered without a category.

Initially, I had a single string as last parameter to `addLogger`; and that, I thought, was the root cause (as described in my solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238973/671366). However, even with that fixed (see above the `array('myplg')`, I see those unrelated log entries being written to my logfile.

Anybody got an idea how to get rid of these superfluous error messages (preferrably by a change in my extension)? Am I doing something wrong in the code shown above? Or is this maybe a Joomla bug?

The only option to fix this at the moment seems to change the Joomla core to log those messages with a category; if I add a category on the `addEntry` calls for these messages, they don't appear anymore in my logfile!

Comment: Is this on a clean Joomla installation? Or do you have things like Akeeba and RocketTheme installed (which I've found override the JLog functionality)?

Comment: I have some extensions installed, but none of the ones you mention. Will try with a clean one

Comment: I would suggest you to try solution mentioned here http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=774242#p3190343

Comment: an interesting approach, but that plugin only seems to remove the message from the output to the user, but not from the log (also see the question linked by me above: this question is about the logfile, not user-shown messages!); and that workaround also is specific for the "Can't identify browser version" message, and wouldn't work for the "FinderIndexerAdapter..." message; and anyway,  my goal is to find a generic solution for only showing log messages from my plugin in its logfile. I'm somehow more and more convinced that this is actually a bug in Joomla core, will have to dig into that :(